# Why does computingMap support identity equality for keys against equals()?

Tags: guava

I've been reading that ComputingMap only supports identity equality and not the equals(). Can someone clarify why?

Comment: I think that "why" questions are better directed to the owners of the library on their discussion group:  https://groups.google.com/group/guava-discuss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for all concurrent maps built using [MapMaker](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html), equals() is used for strong references and identity equality is used for weak and soft references.

See [softKeys](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html#softKeys()), [weakKeys](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html#weakKeys()), [softValues](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html#softValues()), [weakValues](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html#weakValues()).

Comment: Fair enough, but *why* does it use identity equality for weak/soft references? Why couldn't they use equals()?

Comment: References may be claimed by the GC anytime. This policy allows the map to guarantee that clients can never observe a partially-reclaimed entry.